# Delphi - convert bmp to png fails

Tags: delphi, bitmap, png

I have the following simple code to convert clipboard image to bmp and then to png:

```
if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_PICTURE) then
begin
    bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    png := TPNGImage.Create;
    try
        bitmap.Assign(Clipboard);
        bitmap.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(application.ExeName) + '\filename.bmp');
        png.Draw(bitmap.Canvas, Rect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
        png.SaveToFile(extractfilepath(application.ExeName) + '\filename.png');
    finally
        bitmap.free;
        png.free;
    end;
end;
```

While the conversion to bmp works and I can even open it in mspaint and see its content, the conversion to png fails and I have a blank png image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you get out of the habit of sharing 1 **try..finally** amongst multiple resources. If `TPNGImage.Create;` fails, you will have leaked an instance of TBitmap. Rather use a separate try..finally per resouce. I.e. `Outer := Txx.Create; try Inner := Txx.Create; try ... finally Inner.Free; end; finally Outer.Free; end;`

Comment: IMO, use CF_BITMAP if available.  That is probably what is happening anyway (both formats are often presented together, you test for CF_PICTURE but you end up retrieving CF_BITMAP). But in the case where CF_BITMAP is present but CF_PICTURE is not, your code wouldn't even execute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have not set the dimensions (height and width) of the PNG image object. You would need to do that before drawing to it.

Easier however would be a simple assignment:

```
png.Assign(Bitmap);
```